# SQL date comparision in yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not being that great at sql, i've reached my limit.
I have a date in the `yyyy/mm/dd` format and i need to get all records "from a week ago"
I think i need some conversion stuff to be done cause this

```
d.date_begin >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
```

is not working :), i'm TERRIBLE at convert and data type..

Comment: Is the date column a string?

Comment: Conversion implies changing from one datatype to another. If stored as Date or Datetime, no conversion is required. Instead, you are simply querying. If stored as a varchar, you've got bigger problems than just one query

Comment: Please include the type of `date_begin`. Also update your question with what `is not working` means

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: date and datetime are not stored by any format.See http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp#DtFormatsInput

Comment: the date begin is a "nvarchar"

Comment: Dont store dates in nvarchar columns. use Date/DateTime/DateTime2 or Time data type instead.

Comment: It's not my making, and i can't change that :/

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you want records from 7 days ago up to and including today's records

```
CAST(d.date_begin AS DATE) >= CAST(DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

Comment: this answer has the same problems I described under @JohnHC's answer

Comment: @t-clausen.dk if you run the below query bellow. you will notice the difference based on the date format in the question 
SELECT '2017/05/26' as , cast('2017/05/26' as date) date

Comment: I know there is a difference. I am referring to performance issues

Answer (score 1):

```
where DATEDIFF(month,Your_date_column,getdate()) < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL server 2012 onwards, if `date_begin` is of datatype `date`

```
where d.date_begin >= cast(DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()) as date)
```

This will get anything in the last 7 days, regardless of time

Comment: This seems to work, i've got another problem that i'll display in another thread i guess. But this function does what i wanted. Thanks to everyone

Comment: Does the "cast" cost a lot of ressources ? It seems my query is going very very slow. I search by 2 criterias and i'm not sure if there is a way to prioritise one rather than the other.

Comment: @VinceLeRouge every row in your table will have d.date_begin converted to a date in order to compare - this is because the right side expression returns a date. This conversion takes a long time and can't use index, which makes it slow. This method does not work well

Answer (score 0):

You should store date/time values using native formats.  Ok, sometimes we cannot.  But you can easily convert your values to the correct format:

```
where cast(replace(d.date_begin, '/', '') as date) >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

I should note that SQL Server is pretty good about conversions, so your initial code should not generate any errors -- unless you have unusual internationalization settings.

Or, actually, a better way to do this is to convert the current value to a string:

```
where d.date_begin >= format(dateadd(day, -7, getdate()), 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

This is better because it is "sargable", meaning that SQL Server can use an index on the column if available.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name
WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND date < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't manipulate d.date_begin. Making calculation on a column while comparing can give bad performance. You should manipulate getdate() to get the same format as d.date_begin. In this case it works because the format is yyyy/MM/dd - the comparison will give the same result as if both columns were date columns.

```
WHERE
  d.date_begin >= convert(char(10),DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE()), 111)
```